# Адаптивный дизайн сайта

Tags: html, css

Опыт создания `html` с использованием `css` есть, но адаптивный дизайн делаю первый раз. Проблема такая, при открытии на телефоне он соответствует дизайну, но все очень мелкое.

Так выглядит на компьютере:

[image: img1]

Так должно выглядеть на телефоне:

[image: img2]

А так выглядит на самом деле:

[image: img3]

Архив с html и css: http://goo.gl/6YcdC

Comment: вы в адаптивном блоке все проставили и ширину и отступы но про размер шрифта как бы забыли... Может стоит его тоже в em размерности вывести? добавить характеристику font-size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это связано с отличиями в разрешении матриц настольного монитора и handheld-девайсов.

Как верно заметил тов. [@Crasher](/users/3358/crasher), нужно оперировать мета-параметром `viewport`. Только запрет масштабирования тут не при чем. Было такое св-во `target-densitydpi`, но его выпилили. Нужно указать `width=device-width` и поэкспериментировать с `initial-scale=...`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Мне это когда-то помогло.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!
Только еще дописал user-scalable=no

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: При выявлении проблем с размером текста на телефонах, нужно указать свойство `max-height: 999999px` для проблемных элементов (значение не важно, важно наличие самого св-ва). Я этот хак вообще прописываю в самом начале css файла:
`* {
        max-height: 999999px;
    }`

Comment: Да что вы плюсуете-то?! device-width уже тоже не поддерживается. Последний раз, когда я об этом слышал, оно было deprecated

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta name="viewport" id="meta-viewport" content="user-scalable=no"/>
```

или

```
<meta name="viewport" id="meta-viewport" content="width=480px,user-scalable=no"/>
```